# How can I edit header in dll file?

Tags: dll, exe, windbg

I have exe file and, that uses my own .dll library. When I launch exe file I get the error

```
The procedure entry point for SomeFunction could not be located in the 
dynamic link library mylib.dll.
```

How can I fix this problem ? Is this possible to change the header in .dll using CFF Explorer or Windbg ?

Comment: Recompile the exe?

Comment: no, I can't do this, there have to be other way to do this.

Comment: You can't? Why not?

Comment: do you compile your dll do you export somefunction() in your dll either using def file or with declspec dllexport